# DRF inserting relative urls to models.URLField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am posting a `relative url` to a model DRF which includes a `models.URLField`. The problem is that it returns for the field `insert a valid internet address`. I know that the problem is with `is_valid` method. Also, I know that I can edit the `relative url` at both sides to be an `absolute url`. But I do not know how to handle the problem to just allow `relative urls` too. Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean 'relative url' something that not starts with 'http://' of 'https://'?

Comment: Yes. I do not want to repeat constant part of the URL uselessly.

Comment: Unfortunately validation of this field checks against regex only. More about validation you can  read in documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/validators/#django.core.validators.URLValidator If you don't want to have http:// or other transport protocol  schema in url, then you can use CharField with your own validation

Comment: That is weird to me. I think it is a very common need.

Answer (score 1):

According to the source code `URLField` doesn't support relative urls, so you can implement `RelativeURLField` by yourself.

In order to do that you would probably need to imeplement a custom `RelativeURLValidator` as well. Then you can connect everything together.

## Example

### RelativeURLValidator

```py
import re

from django.utils.regex_helper import _lazy_re_compile
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class RelativeURLValidator(RegexValidator):
    regex = _lazy_re_compile(r"^(?:[/?#][^\s]*)?\Z", re.IGNORECASE)
    message = _("Enter a valid Relative URL.")
```

This is an example of simple validator implementation. It is based on `RegexValidator` that allows to defined a custom regular expression in order to handle validation.

The regular expression matches string that starts with `/`, `?`, or `#` + a non-breakable sequence till the end of the string.

### RelativeURLField

```py
from django.db.models import CharField
from django.forms import TextInput
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class RelativeURLField(CharField):
    widget = TextInput
    default_error_messages = {"invalid": _("Enter a valid Relative URL.")}
    default_validators = [RelativeURLValidator()]
```

The `RelativeURLField` above is a simple field that is based on `CharField` with a few changes:

1. It has customized default error message.
2. It uses the `RelativeURLValidator` created in the first step.

### Usage

The usage is simple as that:

```py
from django.db import models


class Post(models.Model):
    url = RelativeURLField()
```